# Calculating the Lagrangian and the equation of motion.

Tags: classical-mechanics

A mass $m$ is attached to the end of a light inextensible string, which is wound around a cylindrical wheel of radius $a$. The moment of inertia of the wheel, about an axis perpendicular to the wheel, is $I$. The axis of the wheel is horizontal, gravity acts downwards with magnitude g.

Let $q$ be the angle rotated by the wheel. Calculate the kinetic energy and potential energies of the system in terms of $q$ and $\dot{q}$. Hence calculate the Lagrangian and derive the equation of motion.

This was our homework for last week but we haven't gotten the answer to it yet and I just don't know how to go about it. 
[Diagram of the situatuion given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnoWi.png)

Comment: This is a mechanics question, not mathematics? Write down an equation for the kinetic and potential energies, and the relationship between the height of the mass and the roration of the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating the wheel through an angle $q$ raises the mass through a distance $qa$, so the GPE is $mgaq$ (up to an additive constant, which is arbitrary in our Lagrangian). We can take $L=T-U$ with$$T=\frac12(I+ma^2)\dot{q}^2,\,U=mgaq.$$The EOM is$$(I+ma^2)\ddot{q}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dT}{d\dot{q}}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dL}{d\dot{q}}=\frac{dL}{dq}=-\frac{dU}{dq}=-mga.$$